# R: Find Minimum Value in Column of Data Frame that is Greater Than or Equal to Row Value of Column in a Different Data Frame

Tags: r, dataframe

First time asking a question (be gentle) since I haven't been able to find anything that works.

In R I have two data frames. One (DataFrameA) has a column with a list of unique dates. The other (DataFrameB) also has a list of dates. But some dates in DataFrameB may not exist in DataFrameA. When that is the case, I want to update the date in DataFrameB to the minimum date from DataFrameA that is greater than the date in DataFrameB.

In SQL I'd probably do something like this:

```
Select MyDate as OldDate, 
(select min(MyDate) from DataFrameA where MyDate >= B.MyDate) as NewDate 
from DataFrameB as B
```

My goal is to update the MyDate Column in each row of DataFrameB with the correct value from DataFrameA.

So if DataFrame B starts out with

```
2019-01-01
2019-01-02
2019-01-03
2019-01-04
2019-01-05
```

and DataFrameA only has

```
2019-01-01
2019-01-03
2019-01-05
```

DataFrameB will end up looking like

```
2019-01-01
2019-01-03
2019-01-03
2019-01-05
2019-01-05
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL solution proposed by the OP directly can be implemented in R using the `sqldf` package:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("Select MyDate as OldDate, 
(select min(MyDate) from DataFrameA where MyDate >= B.MyDate) as NewDate 
from DataFrameB as B")
```

> ```
>      OldDate    NewDate
> 1 2019-01-01 2019-01-01
> 2 2019-01-02 2019-01-03
> 3 2019-01-03 2019-01-03
> 4 2019-01-04 2019-01-05
> 5 2019-01-05 2019-01-05
> ```

Note that `MyDate` are character dates as mentioned by the OP in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59604729/r-find-minimum-value-in-column-of-data-frame-that-is-greater-than-or-equal-to-r#comment105373860_59604761) (actually, they are of type `factor` as `data.frame()` turns strings into factors by default.)

#### Data

```
DataFrameB <- data.frame(MyDate = as.character(as.Date("2019-01-01") + 0:4))
DataFrameA <- DataFrameB[c(TRUE, FALSE), , drop = FALSE]
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use a non-equi join with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dates <- setDT(dfA)[dfB, min(date),on = .(date >= date), 
             allow.cartesian = TRUE, by = .EACHI]$V1
dfB$date <- dates
dfB
#         date
#1: 2019-01-01
#2: 2019-01-03
#3: 2019-01-03
#4: 2019-01-05
#5: 2019-01-05
```

---

Or using `findInterval` from `base R`

```
dfA$date[findInterval(dfB$date, dfA$date, left.open = TRUE) + 1]
#[1] "2019-01-01" "2019-01-03" "2019-01-03" "2019-01-05" "2019-01-05"
```

#### data

```
dfB <- structure(list(date = structure(c(17897, 17898, 17899, 17900, 
17901), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

dfA <- structure(list(date = structure(c(17897, 17899, 17901), 
         class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This looks like it might have worked except that my "dates" are actually characters and it would only let me  use "==" not ">=". I was able to get other solution working faster. Thank you for your quick response, though.

Comment: @cocoder  I would use `as.Date` to first convert to Date class.  anyway, looks like you are not interested in efficient options

Answer (score 0):

I would use simple data frame manipulation:

```
#prepare the data frames:
a <- data.frame(as.Date("2019-01-01") + 0:4)
b <- data.frame(c(a[1],a[3],a[5]))

#filter the a based on b
for (i in 1:nrow(a)) {
  pos <- min(which(b[,1] >= a[i,1]))
  a[i,1] <- b[pos,1] 

}
#done
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, here is also a completely different approach which uses an *update in an anti-join* and a subsequent *next observation carried backwards*:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DataFrameB)[!setDT(DataFrameA), on = "MyDate", MyDate := NA][
  , MyDate := zoo::na.locf0(MyDate, fromLast = TRUE)][]
```

> ```
>        MyDate
> 1: 2019-01-01
> 2: 2019-01-03
> 3: 2019-01-03
> 4: 2019-01-05
> 5: 2019-01-05
> ```

or in a more elaborate version which reproduces the expected result:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DataFrameB)[, OldDate := MyDate][
  !setDT(DataFrameA), on = "MyDate", MyDate := NA][
    , c("NewDate", "MyDate") := .(zoo::na.locf0(MyDate, fromLast = TRUE), NULL)][]
```

> ```
>       OldDate    NewDate
> 1: 2019-01-01 2019-01-01
> 2: 2019-01-02 2019-01-03
> 3: 2019-01-03 2019-01-03
> 4: 2019-01-04 2019-01-05
> 5: 2019-01-05 2019-01-05
> ```

The *update in anti-join* sets all dates which are *not* contained in `DataFrameA` to NA:

```
setDT(DataFrameB)[!setDT(DataFrameA), on = "MyDate", MyDate := NA][]
```

> ```
>        MyDate
> 1: 2019-01-01
> 2:       <NA>
> 3: 2019-01-03
> 4:       <NA>
> 5: 2019-01-05
> ```

#### Data

```
DataFrameB <- data.frame(MyDate = as.character(as.Date("2019-01-01") + 0:4))
DataFrameA <- DataFrameB[c(TRUE, FALSE), , drop = FALSE]
```